# Simple school bank project in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, homework

What is your opinion on this simple school project exercising OOP in C++?

```
class Person {
public:
    Person() = default;
    explicit Person(std::string const& name);
    Person(const std::string& name, int age);
    void setAge(int age);
    void setName(std::string const& name);
    int getAge() const;
    const std::string& getName() const;

private:
    int age{};
    std::string name;
};
Person::Person(const std::string &name, int age) : age(age), name(name) {}

int Person::getAge() const {
    return age;
}

const std::string &Person::getName() const {
    return name;
}
void Person::setAge(int age) {
    Person::age = age;
}
Person::Person(std::string const& name) : name(name) {}
void Person::setName(std::string const& name) {
    Person::name = name;
}

class Client : public Person {
public:
    static int const uuidLen = 37;
    explicit Client(std::string const& name);
    Client(Client const& orig);
    Client& operator=(Client const& rhs);
    ~Client();

    std::string const& getId() const;
private:
    void copyId(char *p);
    char *_id;
    std::string id;
};
void Client::copyId(char*p) {
    _id = new char[Client::uuidLen];
    memcpy(_id, p, Client::uuidLen);
    id = _id;
}

Client::Client(std::string const& name) : Person(name) {
    _id = new char[Client::uuidLen];

    uuid_t uid;
    uuid_generate(uid);
    uuid_unparse(uid, _id);

    id = _id;
}

Client::Client(Client const& orig) : Person(orig.getName()) {
    copyId(orig._id);
    setName(orig.getName());
    setAge(orig.getAge());
}

Client& Client::operator=(Client const& rhs) {
    if(this != &rhs){
        delete[] _id;
        copyId(rhs._id);
        setName(rhs.getName());
        setAge(rhs.getAge());
    }
    return *this;
}

Client::~Client() {
    delete[] _id;
}
std::string const& Client::getId() const {
    return id;
}

class Account {
public:
    static int newNumber;

    explicit Account(Client const& owner);
    void setInterestRate(double interestRate);

    int getNumber() const;
    double getBalance() const;
    double getInterestRate() const;
    Client const& getOwner() const;

    void deposit(double amount);
    bool canWithdraw(double amount) const;
    bool withdraw(double amount);
    void addInterest();

private:
    int number{};
    double balance{};
    double interestRate{};
    Client owner;
};
int Account::newNumber = 0;

Account::Account(Client const& owner) : number(newNumber++), owner(owner), balance(0.0) {}
int Account::getNumber() const {
    return number;
}
double Account::getBalance() const {
    return balance;
}
double Account::getInterestRate() const {
    return interestRate;
}
Client const& Account::getOwner() const {
    return owner;
}
void Account::setInterestRate(double interestRate) {
    //given in percentage
    Account::interestRate = interestRate / 100;
}
bool Account::canWithdraw(double amount) const {
    return (getBalance() - amount) >= 0;
}
void Account::deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
}
bool Account::withdraw(double amount) {
    if(canWithdraw(amount)){
        balance -= amount;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void Account::addInterest() {
    balance += (getBalance() * getInterestRate());
}

class Bank {
public:
    Account& createAccount(Client const& client);
    double totalDeposit(std::string const& uuid) const;
    double deposit(Account& account, double amount);
    double withdraw(Account &account, double amount);
    double setInerest(Account &account, double interest);
    void chargeInterest(Account &account);
    void printStats() const;

private:
    std::vector<Client> clients;
    std::vector<Account> accounts;
};
Account& Bank::createAccount(Client const& client) {
    accounts.emplace_back(client);
    clients.push_back(client);
    return accounts.back();
}

double Bank::totalDeposit(std::string const& uuid) const {
    std::vector<Account> allAccounts;
    std::copy_if(accounts.begin(), accounts.end(), std::back_inserter(allAccounts),
                 [&uuid](Account const& a) { return uuid == a.getOwner().getId(); });
    double total = 0;
    for (Account const& a: allAccounts) {
        total += a.getBalance();
    }
    return total;
}
double Bank::deposit(Account& account, double const amount) {
    account.deposit(amount);
    return amount;
}
double Bank::withdraw(Account& account, double amount) {
    if (!account.withdraw(amount)) {
        throw std::exception();
    }
    return amount;
}
void Bank::chargeInterest(Account& account) {
    account.addInterest();
}
double Bank::setInerest(Account& account, double interest) {
    account.setInterestRate(interest);
    return interest;
}
void Bank::printStats() const {
    for(Client  const& c : clients){
        double total = totalDeposit(c.getId());
        std::cout << "client '" << c.getName() << "' "
        << "has deposit of: " << total << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    Client j("Josef");
    Client p("Petr");

    Bank bank;

    Account& a1 = bank.createAccount(j);
    Account& a2 = bank.createAccount(p);

    bank.deposit(a1, 8500);
    bank.printStats();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`setAge`, `getAge`, `setName`, `getName` are trivial getter/setters. This pattern is an often repeated mistake, and has nothing better than declaring `age` and `name` as `public:`, because they don't provide encapsulation and sanity checks at all.

I don't see any good reason to use `char*` as type of `_id`.

The destructor of `Person` should be `virtual`.

Your design of relationship between `Account` and `Client` has a big problem, because each `Account` should hold a reference of `Client`, so that when some `Client` information is changed, all `Account`s that have owner as that `Client` should reflect that change.

I suggest something like this:

````
class Client {
// ...
    int client_id;
// ...
};


class Bank {
// ...
unordered_map<int, Client> clients; // holds (client id, client object) pairs
// ...

    const Client& getClient(int id) const {
        return clients.find(id)->second;
    }
};

class Account {
    Bank& bank; // reference

    const Client& getOwner() const {
        return bank.getClient(client_id);
    }
    
    int client_id;
};

```
````

Comment: And there was even error I did not even notice. In the main function, I am using reference to account `Account& a1 = bank.createAccount(j)`, but after that, I created another client which invalidates the reference to the first one (since the vector reallocates its internal storage by the `accounts.emplace_back(client)`. So I think I should use `std::deque` instead, if I want to use references to the container elements (since the `std::deque` does not invalidate if new memory is needed). That was big mistake

Comment: And for your points: 1)Using getters/setters may not now use any encapsulation, but they can in the future, making them public would disable this. 2) I would not use `char *_id` if I have not to, but I am getting the UUID from `uuid_generate`, which I have to pass buffer to store the result, this is the only option (and from that buffer, I create `std::string`). I do not know about possibility in which I would give ownership to `std::string` directly (without any temporary buffer). 3) making virtual destructor for child classes is good point, thanks for this.

Comment: 4) And yes, the overall design of the bank is not ideal (having 2 vectors for cliens and accounts separately). But that is mandatory from the school specs (And I doubt the reasoning for this decision as well). If I were to make my own choice over the bank design, I would probably go for `std::unordered_map<std::string, Client> clients` (mapping between UUID and the client) and `std::unordered_map<Client, std::vector<Accounts>> accounts`, since one client can have multiple Accounts.